# openGL2.0: How to disable vertex shaders?

Tags: vertex-shader, opengl-2.0

I am trying to capture traces from a game but the glInterceptor I use doesn't support vertex shaders. My research suggests I disable vertex shaders and use the default vertex shader but no information about how to do it. So, how can I disable vertex shaders? Here is the code:

pp.fx

```
#define DISABLE_FOG
#define DISABLE_LIGHTING

technique Default
{
  pass P0
  {
    VertexShader = vertexShaders/diff-tex.vs;
    PixelShader = pixelShaders/pp.ps;

    #ifdef ENABLE_TWOSIDED
        EnableCulling = FALSE;
    #endif

    #ifdef DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST
        EnableDepthTest = FALSE;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_ADDITIVE
        EnableDepthMask = FALSE;
        EnableBlending = TRUE;
        BlendFuncSrc = ONE;
        BlendFuncDst = ONE;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_MULTIPLICATIVE
        EnableDepthMask = FALSE;
        EnableBlending = TRUE;
        BlendFuncSrc = DST_COLOR;
        BlendFuncDst = ZERO;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_ALPHA_BLENDING
        EnableDepthMask = FALSE;
        EnableBlending = TRUE;
        BlendFuncSrc = SRC_ALPHA;
        BlendFuncDst = ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_PREMULT_ALPHA_BLENDING
        EnableDepthMask = FALSE;
        EnableBlending = TRUE;
        BlendFuncSrc = ONE;
        BlendFuncDst = ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    #endif
  }
}
```

diff-tex.vs

```
#include "../commons/defines.sh"
#include "../commons/attributes.sh"
#include "../commons/uniforms.sh"
#include "../commons/functions.sh"
#include "../commons/varyings.sh"

void main()
{


#ifdef ENABLE_SKINNING
    // bone 1 influence
    int i = int(DT_BONEINDICES.x);
    float w = DT_BONEWEIGHTS.x;
    mat4 bonetm = BONEWORLDTM[i];
    vec3 worldpos = transform(bonetm, DT_POSITION) * w;

    #ifndef DISABLE_LIGHTING
    V_Normal = rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_NORMAL ) * w;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_NORMALMAP
    vec3 worldtangent = rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_TANGENT ) * w;
    #endif

    // bone 2 influence
    i = int(DT_BONEINDICES.y);
    w = DT_BONEWEIGHTS.y;
    bonetm = BONEWORLDTM[i];
    worldpos += transform(bonetm, DT_POSITION) * w;

    #ifndef DISABLE_LIGHTING
    V_Normal += rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_NORMAL ) * w;
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_NORMALMAP
    worldtangent += rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_TANGENT ) * w;
    #endif

    // bone 3 influence
    i = int(DT_BONEINDICES.z);
    w = (1.0 - DT_BONEWEIGHTS.y - DT_BONEWEIGHTS.x);
    bonetm = BONEWORLDTM[i];
    worldpos += transform(bonetm, DT_POSITION) * w;

    // Can be omitted for optimization, effect is quite small
    #ifndef DISABLE_LIGHTING
    V_Normal += rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_NORMAL ) * w;
    V_Normal = normalize(V_Normal);
    #endif

    #ifdef ENABLE_NORMALMAP
    worldtangent += rotate( convertToMat3(bonetm), DT_TANGENT ) * w;
    worldtangent = normalize(worldtangent);

    vec3 worldbinormal = cross( V_Normal, worldtangent );
    #endif

    gl_Position = VIEWPROJTM * vec4(worldpos, 1);
#else

    #if defined(DISABLE_TRANSFORM_EXCEPT_ORIENTATION)
    // Vertices are already in screen space coordinates
    gl_Position = PROJTM * vec4(DT_POSITION, 1);
    #elif defined(DISABLE_TRANSFORM)
    gl_Position = vec4(DT_POSITION, 1);
    #else
    // Transform coordinates to screen space
    gl_Position = TOTALTM * vec4(DT_POSITION, 1);
    vec3 worldpos = vec3(WORLDTM * vec4(DT_POSITION, 1));
    #endif
#endif
}
```

Comment: That question doesn't really make sense. You cannot just "disable vertex shaders". The application might use them or not. So that would mean that the application actually have to implement an alternative code path for implementations not supporting shaders, and you could trigger that by either setting some option, or make your gl interceptor lie about the featuers which are available. But if the application does not already support that, you have to rewrite it, which means you will need access to the source code. The shader codes you pasted are completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @derhass thank you for your answer. The instructions of the gl interceptor were to disable vertex shaders and I could not understand what it meant. Turns out that some applications have an option to disable vertex shaders. I downloaded another game (with the source code this time) and I will try to make some changes to this one, as you suggested.